# Shell script to tail a log file and output it to another file till specific string is found?

Tags: shell, grep

I have to write  the output of  a log file using tail to another file till it finds the string .

Log file contains-

```
  I am Rahul.
  I have 5 oranges.
  The end.
  Something something.
```

Till " the end " ,I want everything to written to another file.

```
tail -f var/log/output.log 
| grep -m 1 "The end" | tee 
Abc.txt
```

But only "the end" is getting  written on abc.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -f file | sed '/The end/q' | tee outfile
```

Sed prints all lines until it reads "The end", at which point it quits.

Also recently [asked in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1284764).

Answer (score 2):

`grep` could not be used here because `grep` is used to extract lines matching some pattern from a stream or a file, and in this case you want to *stop* outputting when a particular string is found.  In essence, you would have to give `grep` some pattern that matched all lines before the `The end.` line, and no line after it.

---

```
sed '/The end\./q'
```

This command would output each line from its standard input stream until a line that contains the string `The end.` is seen. At that point, that final line would be outputted and the `sed` command would terminate due to executing the `q` command in the `sed` script.

As part of your pipeline:

```
tail -f var/log/output.log |
sed '/The end\./q' |
tee Abc.txt
```

Depending on the implementation of the `tail` command, this pipeline would terminate as soon as the `The end.` line is encountered, or as soon as `tail -f` tried to write to the non-existing `sed` process, i.e. as soon as the `The end.` line had been seen by `sed` and the `Something something.` line was outputted by `tail -f`.

`tail` on OpenBSD (which does not behave as POSIX `tail`) exhibits the behavior described last, while GNU `tail` would give the first behavior (immediate termination once the `The end.` line is encountered).

Comment: But how to terminate the script as soon as this line is executed?

Comment: Could you please tell me @kusalananda

Comment: My script is still struck on that tail command, I just want to terminate it after the task

Comment: @GauravBaghel Then I presume that there is no line with `The end.` in your data quite yet.

Comment: After the end there are lines , how to stop after completing this task

Comment: Its a log file which is recording the messages, but I after The end string i want to to terminate the tail function

Comment: @GauravBaghel I would guess that the pattern you are using does not match the data in the file. Does your file contain a line with the actual text `The end.`? Or is it `the end` or something completely different from what you've shown in the question?

Comment: Yes it is writing till "The end" line also, it its the case whaylt you are saying then output file will not contain lines till the end .